# Error from 7z cannot open <file>.tmp Permission denied

Tags: unix, 7zip, autosys

I have an archiving script that uses 7z -tzip -aoa and it runs on unix and works fine. But when run through Autosys, it always fails when trying to archive a second file to an existing archive. The error is:

7-Zip 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=C,Utf16=off,HugeFiles=on,8 CPUs)

Scanning

Updating archive 
20150807.zip

Error:
7-Zip cannot open file
20150807.zip.tmp
Permission denied

It doesn't tell me where it's having permissions with that tmp file, so I don't know where to look. I've set all the permissions to any folders that I thought it might be using to 777, but the problem persists. It works great when not using Autosys.

## I found the comment below but it seems to be relevant only to Windows. I'd like to know how I can make this work on UNIX.

I tried to search for a while on the net, but couldn't find any help, so here I am.
My first problem is when I try to compress a folder in C:// with the context menus (7-zip > Add to "xyz.zip"), I get the error : "Access is denied. 7-zip cannot open file "xyz.zip.tmp"
I can however open the file manager in the 7-zip folder ("7zFM"), run as administrator and compress the said file to .zip.
It seems to be a security issue about C:// directory, since it seems that I can compress other files and folders just fine. 
Any help?

Link
Shell 
Shell 
2012-07-29
You have guessed right. You can either 1) run 7-Zip as administrator or 2) set the working directory in 7-Zip File Manager (Tools->Options->Folders) to an unprotected one (for example, clear the checkbox there) and use the "Add to archive…" menu and create the archive in an unprotected directory.

Answer (score 1):

Set the working directory using the -w switch.

Comment: thank you. that works to bypass the problem. I still would like to understand where the .tmp file is being created by default, such that it doesn't have permissions. It obviously has permissions in the folder where the .zip file is being created - why should the .tmp be different?

Comment: by default the .tmp file is created in the working directory, the directory you get using the command `pwd`

Answer (score 0):

7z **does not use current directory** (the one you get by `pwd`) as a working directory. It uses the one that the resulting archive is going to be created at.

For example:

`/tmp $ 7z a /folder.7z /folder`

will ignore the fact you're in `/tmp` and will first create a tmp file in `/` and then put the result in the `/` **no matter what you current folder is**.

If you don't have access to create files in `/` but you do have access to update the archive that's already there (a very valid scenario) you're going to get exactly what you get:

```
/tmp $ 7z a /folder.7z /folder

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_US.utf8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,4 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz (806E9),ASM,AES-NI)

Open archive: /folder.7z
--
Path = /folder.7z
Type = 7z
Physical Size = 150
Headers Size = 150
Solid = -
Blocks = 0

Scanning the drive:
1 folder, 2 files, 0 bytes

Updating archive: /folder.7z

Items to compress: 3


Error:
cannot open file
/folder.7z.tmp
Permission denied


System ERROR:
Unknown error -2147024883
```

Also, in case you're omitting the archive name from the command line, it's going to use directory of your source.
For example, when you do this:

`7z a /folder`

it is going to use `/` as a working directory - it will attempt to create temp file in `/` and will put the resulting archive there as well.

To fix that just make sure that the archive name is in your command line and that you have file create permission to the folder the archive is going to be created (sometimes you have access to update the archive itself but can't create new files in the dame folder)